# Hit breakpoint in dynamically loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

What setting does Visual Studio need in order for it to hit a breakpoint in a dynamically loaded assembly(dll)? The initial dll(which is a WCF service library) delegates to a static factory class and has it's breakpoints recognized just fine. I am able to step through up to the point the static factory loads the dll but, after it successfully loads an assembly(dll) on disk, the breakpoints I have set in that separate Class Library project(the dll I am trying to debug) do not get hit. In other words, I am expecting for the source code and those debugging symbols to be recognized and presented to me in the Active Document window, ready for me to start stepping through with F9. Instead the original WCF project's client reports a status the the service was invoked and completed successfully. Any help will be greatly appreciated. All these projects are located in the same Visual Studio solution.

```
string typeInAssembly = "fully.qualified.typeName";

IInterfacedynDll dynDll = null;

Assembly someAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

Type dynDllType = someAssembly.GetType(typeInAssembly);

dynDll = (IInterfacedynDll)Activator.CreateInstance(dynDllType);
```

Comment: Have you tried the modules window (Ctrl + D, M) to make sure that the symbols are actually being loaded?

Comment: You will need to load debug information for this particular assembly. As @Brandon suggested you should check the modules window for more information. It will display all currently loaded dlls and the status of symbol loading. In case that symbols for the assembly weren't loaded automatically you will have to set symbols path on your own.

Comment: Thanks to both Brandon and Ivan. Your comments pointed in the right direction to get this resolved. Once I figured out how to access the Modules window and subsequently how to use it, as in how to specify the file path to the pdb & dll files, it just worked perfectly. Thanks :)